# How to get all class properties (in Python) of a GAE polymodel including those defined via @property

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, polymodel

I am using the Google App Engine polymodel to model data that can have more than one instance of a property - e.g. a contact could have multiple phone numbers.  Say this is my setup:

```
class Foo(polymodel.PolyModel):
    some_prop = ndb.StringProperty()

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return Bar.query(Bar.foo == self.key)

class Bar(ndb.Model):
    foo = ndb.KeyProperty(kind = Foo)
    other_prop= ndb.StringProperty()
```

(I got this approach after reading this GAE article on data modeling: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling)

Now when I do:

```
Foo._properties
```

I only get access to the following:

```
{'some_prop': StringProperty('some_prop'), 
 'class': _ClassKeyProperty('class', repeated=True)}
```

Is there any way to access to ALL properties, including those defined with "@property"?

Many thanks for any help or or insight on where I'm going wrong.
- Lee

UPDATE:
Based on @FastTurle's great answer, I've now added a class method that returns both class properties as well as methods tagged as properties via @property:

```
def props(self):
    return dict(self._properties.items() +  \
                   {attr_name:getattr(self,attr_name) for \
                    attr_name, attr_value in \
                    Foo.__dict__.iteritems() if \
                    isinstance(attr_value,property)}.items())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performing `Foo._properties` should get you access to any attributes you define on your `polymodel.PolyModel` that inherit from `google.appengine.ext.db.Property`.

This means that `KeyProperty`, `StringProperty`, etc... will show up in `Foo._properties`, so I'm assuming you now need to find all the methods decorated by `property`.

Fortunately, this isn't that hard. First, a quick sidetrack into decorators (forgive me if you know this already).

In python [decorators are just syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators). For example, these two methods result in the same thing:

```
@property
def bar(self):
    pass

def bar(self):
    pass
bar = property(bar)
```

Fortunately for us, `property(obj)` returns a new `property` object. This also means that `@property` returns a `property` object as well. You can kind of think of `property` as a class! And finally can use `isinstance(bar, property)` to see if `bar` is a property.

Finally, we can put this into use by examining each of `Foo`'s attributes and selecting only those that are `property` instances.

```
for attr_name, attr_value in Foo.__dict__.iteritems():
    if isinstance(attr_value, property):
        print attr_name, attr_value

# bar, <property object at ...>
```

Comment: FastTurtle: wow, was not expecting this high-quality level response so quick: thanks so much! My code is now looking much nicer + I learned more about decorators. I've edited my answer to show the class method I added to return both properties and methods that are property objs. Hopefully that makes sense.  Many thanks for your help here, greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: @pixelphantom Glad to hear that my answer was helpful! The method you added looks good and hopefully does what you want. Good luck :)